# Get name of next doctrine migration

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

How could I get the name / version of the next migration to execute? Something similar to `migrations:latest` but more like `migrations:next`. I need this as input to another command so it needs to be parseable output (can't really just use `migrations:status`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Configuration` object of the Doctrine migrations bundle. This is even (somewhat) documented as [custom configuration](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/2.1/reference/custom-configuration.html.).

Here is a minimal code example that works for me:

```php
public function migrationVersionAction(EntityManagerInterface $em, ParameterBagInterface $parameters) {
    $connection = $em->getConnection();
    $configuration = new \Doctrine\Migrations\Configuration\Configuration($connection);
    $configuration->setMigrationsNamespace($parameters->get('doctrine_migrations.namespace'));
    $configuration->setMigrationsDirectory($parameters->get('doctrine_migrations.dir_name'));
    $configuration->setMigrationsTableName($parameters->get('doctrine_migrations.table_name'));

    return new JsonResponse([
       'prev' => $configuration->resolveVersionAlias('prev'),
       'current' => $configuration->resolveVersionAlias('current'),
       'next' => $configuration->resolveVersionAlias('next'),
       'latest' => $configuration->resolveVersionAlias('latest')
    ]);
}
```

You might want to set the remaining parameters as well though, especially if they differ from the defaults. For this, the [configuration documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/2.1/reference/configuration.html#migrations-configuration) might help in addition to the link above.